# Google analytics filter - danger of losing data

Tags: google-analytics

I keep seeing things like "And, you should always create a different profile for filters. Keep a separate raw profile with no filters" implying that you can permanently lose data if you set up filters incorrectly. Can someone explain what the danger is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters can remove some data or all data.

Since you cannot go back in time with Google Analytics and recover data, that data can be lost for good.

If you keep an additional "raw" or unfiltered profile, you have not lost any data that a filter may remove on purpose or by accident.

It's real easy to screw up a filter and inadvertently remove all your data.

From Google:

> > Incorrect filter settings can affect the data you see, and can inadvertently filter all of your data from your reports.